# Rails render a page from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, render

I am trying to use IMGKit to create an image of a webpage that I have.  What I would like to do is to create an image while on a different webpage.  In order to accomplish that I have some code that looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.jpeg do
    dashboards_response = render controller: :dashboards
    image = IMGKit.new(dashboards_response[0]).to_img(:jpg)
    send_data(image, type: "image/jpeg", filename: "data.jpeg", disposition: "inline")
  end
end
```

I would like to respond to a jpeg by rendering another page.  This fails with a Template is missing error, which is really strange.  In order to debug this, I moved the render call outside of the respond_to block on DoubleRenderError.  I'm not sure how to proceed on this, can anyone provide some insight?

Thanks